# VGA monitor panel "twitches" between normal and slightly yellow on MacBook but works perfectly on Windows laptop

Tags: macbook, vga, external-display, adapter, usb-c

I have a cheap Lenovo 1920x1080 flat planel VGA display, a 7-year old HP ProBook and a new M1 MacBook Air.

When I connect the monitor to the PC laptop it just works perfectly.

When I connect the monitor to the Mac via a cheap but new USB-C to VGA adaptor the screen sometimes just works perfectly, but other times the white background will twitch to a slightly yellowish hue and back. Like one bit of colour information is unstable perhaps?

I've tried disconnecting and reconnecting the adaptor to the Mac and the adaptor to the VGA cable, both with the Mac running and suspended. This has no effect.

If I check the connection between the VGA cable and the monitor it always seemes tight but if I unplug the cable from the monitor and plug it back in this sometimes fixes the problem. The same problem never happens with the same cable and the same monitor when plugged into the PC laptop without an adaptor.

Is the USB-C to VGA adaptor the ony possible fault? Is this a known problem? Googling for flickering monitors unfortunately returns results about many completely different problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is highly probable that the USB to VGA adapter is faulty.

To be 100% sure that it is the adapter, you would need to test another VGA monitor and a USB to VGA adapter.  However, you have demonstrated the monitor works fine without it.  That being said, USB to VGA adapters, especially cheap ones, are known to get hot internally and fail.  I would replace it and go with a high quality, name brand option if you choose to stay with that method of connection.

Comment: The adapter doesn't get hot. It's very slightly warm, less warm than the MacBook. I should be able to test with another monitor later today.

Comment: I've just tested the same adapter with my older 1680x1050 VGA/DVI monitor. At first I didn't think it was flickering but it did look slightly dull and yellowish on the Mac but looked great on the PC. Finally I noticed that it was flickering but was just a bit harder to see.